# IAM Roles Assume Role Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Given an IAM role created with this permission:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "First"
    }
  ]
}
```

is there anything that tells AWS that only lambda functions in **this** account should be able to assume the role. I want AWS lambda to be able to assume this role when running functions in this account, but only lambda functions running in this AWS account - not lambda functions running in other random AWS account that happen to discover the ARN of this IAM role.

If it is the case that using this configuration allows any lambda function running in any AWS account to assume this role, then how can this policy be amended to only allow lambda functions running in my account to assume this role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"` tells that your IAM role can only be assumed by Lambda.

If you want to grant permissions to another account to assume the role, your IAM policy for the role may look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumberThatCanAssumeTheRole>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ok, so any AWS account in the world running a Lambda function can assume this role if they know the ARN? This would mean if this role is granted access to other resources in my account the ability to assume this role from another account effectively means anyone in the world can do whatever this role can do?

Comment: No. Even if they know the ARN, they cannot assume unless you grant `AssumeRole` permissions to that account to assume the role.

Comment: so, to clarify - even though the policy document doesn't specify any  account restriction, it is a default assumption of how IAM policies work that it applies only to the current AWS account? Is there any documentation you can point to for this?

Comment: Yeah. You can say that. I am not able to find the exact documentation that can explain it but check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html and if you have 2 accounts, play with it and it may clear your doubts.